# Filtering debug output for C#

Tags: c#, debugging, filtering

Is it possible to filter out different sorts of exceptions out of my debug output in C#?

I want to filter out 'System.FormatException', because I know it's going to occur, and it gives a rubbish oversight of my output. I'm scanning a textfile with over 20,000 lines, and almost a quarter of them are wrong, but I don't want 'System.FormatException' 5000 times in my output...

The code is seen below, and you can see, if it's not a number, it will not double.parse, so it will catch the error.

```
if (!(dataline.EndsWith(";0") || intCounter == 0))
{
    try
    {
        natMB = double.Parse(splitline[8], NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    }
    catch
    {
        natMB = 0;
    }

    double intMB;
    try
    {
        intMB = double.Parse(splitline[9], NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
    }
    catch
    {
        intMB = 0;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to validate the input going into the function, in my humble opinion catching an error to validate user input is not ideal. A simple RegEx could do a numerical validation for you.

Comment: I agree. It would be better to fix the input instead of catching an error.

Comment: I added the code that i'm using

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you'd like to ignore an exception you could just put the following try/catch over it:

```
try
{
  // Insert your code here
}
catch(System.FormatException)
{

}
```

Seeing your code I recommend you to use

```
double d = 0;
Boolean success = double.TryParse(splitline[8], out d);

if(success)
  Console.WriteLine("Conversion successful!");
else
  Console.WriteLine("Damnit.");
```

instead. This will return a boolean on whether the conversion went fine or not and also will store the parsed double in the variable you passed the function.

Comment: I am doing that, but It still shows up in my output. I'm try catching wrong data (punctuations, words, ... while they should be numbers), and replacing them by 0.

Comment: Personally I log every error.  In this case I'd try and prevent the error than throw away the logging.  In my experience some of the hardest bugs to find and fix in a live environment are the ones with bad logging.

Comment: @Dashzapp then use TryParse instead of Parse as beta sugests. Also it will improve your performance, as exceptions are known to work long in .net

Comment: debugging ... To Liath: I'm logging every other in an errorlogwriter with detailed information.

Comment: No overload for method 'TryParse' takes 1 arguments error with code : double.TryParse(splitline[8], out d)

Comment: Sorry. Please refresh the page, I just added some example code on how to use it.

Comment: Getting closer, what value does tryparse return? A BOOL or a double?

Comment: I just tested it. If splitline is a String-Array it should work. I initially made a stupid mistake when adding the code, updated it to version two minutes ago.

Answer (score 2):

I find the built-in .NET logging mechanisms frustrating for this sort. I would take a look at something like [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) or [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) which give you a large amount of control over what level is logged and in which namespaces.

Combine these with Log2Console for a live logging trace.

Comment: To clarify I believe @beta 's answer is correct in this situation because it prevents the error occurring - even better solution.  In the situation when you want to filter out errors which have been reported and to filter which are logged take a look at these technologies.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore this exception while debugging, you can disable the catch of the exception.

In the menus, go to: *Debug* → *Exceptions...* (in my Visual Studio, the hotkeys are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>).

Then click on "Find...", and search your exception. When you found it, make sure none of the checkboxes are checked. It should ignore it now.